# Filezilla unable to upload files

Tags: google-compute-engine, filezilla

My Filezilla can connect with instance and download all the files but I could never upload or a create a single file. I checked the permission and it looks fine. I followed the standard procedure to connect using the sftp setting in Filezilla, what could be the possible solution? Did I miss something?

activity:

```
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/wordpress/wp-content"...
Status: Listing directory /wordpress/wp-content
Status: Directory listing of "/wordpress/wp-content" successful
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/wordpress/wp-content/themes"...
Status: Listing directory /wordpress/wp-content/themes
Status: Directory listing of "/wordpress/wp-content/themes" successful
Status: Creating directory '/wordpress/wp-content/themes/bridge'...
Command:    mkdir "bridge"
Error:  mkdir /wordpress/wp-content/themes/bridge: permission denied
Command:    mkdir "/wordpress/wp-content/themes/bridge"
Error:  mkdir /wordpress/wp-content/themes/bridge: permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the directory `/wordpress` on your VM is readable by all users on your system, but only `root` can write to it. You can verify this by connecting to your VM and running:

```
ls -ld /wordpress
```

If you want to be able to manage your files via Filezilla, you need to do either of the following:

1. give your username write access (see [`chmod` and permissions](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm)), or
2. create a [new Linux group and give the group write access](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups), and add yourself to this group

My recommendation would be to use option #2 as that is more general and future-proof.

This is not specific to Google Compute Engine, this is a standard Linux feature.

Comment: I tried your above suggestion, I could see the owner of the file is www-data but i dont know how to add write permission. Is there any elaborate documentation.

Comment: @BhagathGuru — I linked my instructions in #1 and #2 to relevant documentation.